# Cocoa Connection Kit and FTP

Tags: cocoa, ftp

Figured this was a long shot, but I just had to ask.

Looking to find the simplest way to write/put a file up to a web site from within my Cocoa application.  I have no problem reading the file of course, but after changes are made, I would like to be able to put the file back on the server.

The general consensus seems to be to use Connection Kit, so I downloaded all of the source files from their site, but when I try to compile, I end up with no less than 118 errors and 43 warnings.  There are frameworks not found, files missing, and a whole host of other issues, most of which are completely beyond my level of understanding at this point.

a) Is there a pre-compiled version of the framework (or frameworks) I can just drop into my system instead of sorting through this mess?

or

b) On the off chance someone has an alternative solution, is there a simpler route to go to be able to write files to a web site from within a cocoa app?

I suppose this is what I get for leaving my coding career those many years ago and not keeping up with the changing times :)

Answer (score 1):

I basically run ConnectionKit these days. If your need is purely FTP, I strongly advise you instead grab the develop branch of CHRLHandle instead, and use the CURLFTPSession class instead:

https://github.com/karelia/CurlHandle